# laravel 5 error en migracion

Tags: mysql, laravel

Amigos.
Estoy creando un proyecto en laravel 5.5 usando windows, pero al momento de crear las migraciones "php artisan migrate", me arroja este error:

> In Connection.php line 664:
>
> could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = walcor and table_name = migrations)
>
> In Connector.php line 67:
>
> could not find driver

¿A que se debe esto?, ¿como lo soluciono?

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando MySQL? Validaste que tengas habilitado pdo_mysql. Podés validarlo creando un archivo php con <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: si estoy utilizando MySQL, pero al parecer el error es porque hace falta la dependencia de Mysql ¿no? porque por lo que veo pide un driver

Comment: al pasar el comando php -m en la consola aparecen todos los modulos excepto el de mysql

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Debes validar que tengas pdo_mysql habilitado en tu php.ini. Abre el archivo php.ini y revisa que te quede descomentada la línea: extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

```
 ;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
 extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
 ;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

Guarda los cambios y reinicia Apache. Espero te sirva. Saludos.